# Adding a build target in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, testing, build

I've written a bunch of tests for my C++ project using the [Catch testing library](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch). Catch tests can be run easily by

1. Compiling the project like normal, and then
2. Running a file called "test_main.cpp" to initiate the tests.

When using XCode (a Mac-only C++ IDE), I did this by creating a second build target. However, recently I have had to move my code to Visual Studio (a Windows-only C++ IDE). How can I add a build target in Visual Studio such that my entire project compiles as-is, then runs "test_main.cpp"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create extra build target that you create from an existing one (debug or release of desired platform).
In that target's properties you change it's output to the kindof executable you want.
Next you add your test_main.cpp to the project (it will be added to all your targets).

in the properties of every source-file there is an option exclude from build.
So next thing to do is make sure that your test_main.cpp is only included in your next test-target and not in your original targets.

now building the new target will produce your test-app.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use the post build event? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but it might work. I could run "cl test_main.cpp" (or something to that effect) on the command line as a post-build event. Unfortunately, "cl" isn't a recognized command on my system for some reason. Will update when I can test this

Comment: I found also these guidelines https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182465(v=vs.110).aspx, but I am not sure that they apply to test systems other then VS. And it also requires that you have TFS. You may be able to do something more advanced with MS build.

Comment: You will probably have to your catch testing library to your path env. variable  in order to use the post event with the cl command directly. Alternatively you can provide full path to the executable.